# Uniswap V3 AlphaRouter - "Failed to get subgraph pools from any providers"

Tags: node.js, web3js, uniswap

I am trying to swap WETH against MyToken from a previously created Uniswap V3 pool on Arbitrum Rinkeby. When calling AlphaRouter.route, however, I get the following error message

> Failed to get subgraph pools from any providers

What is still missing to swap?
What do I need to create?

My target is to swap WETH for a given output of MyToken.

I am trying to simply get a swap on Uniswap V3 with my pool done. Any ideas?

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const {
  ethers
} = require("ethers");
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const {
  Token,
  CurrencyAmount,
  TradeType,
  Percent
} = require("@uniswap/sdk-core");
const {
  AlphaRouter
} = require('@uniswap/smart-order-router');
const ABI_UNISWAP_POOL_V3 = require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json");
const fs = require('fs');
const JSBI = require('JSBI');

const API_ALCHEMY_ARBITRUM_RINKEBY = 'https://arb-rinkeby.g.alchemy.com/v2/<API KEY>';
const POOL_ADDRESS_MYTOKEN_WETH = '0xc69e7AE1073DD8184FcF6dBfc27ba97d1524716A';

const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync("./.mnemonics").toString().trim();
const hdprovider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, API_ALCHEMY_ARBITRUM_RINKEBY);
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(hdprovider);

const owner = hdprovider.addresses[0];

var web3 = new Web3(hdprovider);
const Contract = web3.eth.Contract;

const router = new AlphaRouter({
  chainId: 421611,
  provider: provider
});

async function main() {
  const MyPool = new Contract(ABI_UNISWAP_POOL_V3.abi, POOL_ADDRESS_MYTOKEN_WETH);

  const [factory, token0, token1, fee, tickSpacing, liquidity, maxLiquidityPerTick] =
  await Promise.all([MyPool.methods.factory().call(),
    MyPool.methods.token0().call(),
    MyPool.methods.token1().call(),
    MyPool.methods.fee().call(),
    MyPool.methods.tickSpacing().call(),
    MyPool.methods.liquidity().call(),
    MyPool.methods.maxLiquidityPerTick().call()
  ]);

  const tokenA = new Token(3, token0, 2, "MTK", "MyToken");
  const tokenB = new Token(3, token1, 18, "WETH", "Wrapped Ether");

  var amountOut = 2000;

  amountOut = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokenA, JSBI.BigInt(amountOut.toString()));
  const slippageTolerance = new Percent(5, 100);
  const deadline = Date.now() + 15000;
  const route = await router.route(
    amountOut,
    tokenB,
    TradeType.EXACT_OUTPUT, {
      recipient: owner,
      slippageTolerance: slippageTolerance,
      deadline: deadline
    }
  );
  hdprovider.engine.stop();
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things are not right in this code:

First is the `amountOut` that you are passing to `router.route` should be converted to `wei`

```
const amountOutInWei=ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountOut.toString(),decimals)
// amountOutInWei should be converted to currentAmount
const currencyAmount= CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(tokenA,JSBI.BigInt(amountOutInWei))
```

`currencyAmount` should be passed to the `router.route(currencyAmount,..)`

Second issue deadline must be in seconds.

```
const deadline=Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)+10*60 // addded 10 minutes
```